# Automatically triggering Macro that executes enter + F2 in table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to achieve a macro that is automatically triggered when data is copied into a table. The macro should execute ENTER + F2 in the whole table.

So far I have this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B8")) Is Nothing Then

        Range("Input_Table").Select
        Selection.Value = Selection.FormulaR1C1

    End If
End Sub
```

Cell B8 is the top left cell of my table, which is called "Input_Table".

The macro works in itself but triggering it automatically by copying a whole bunch of data into the table often crashes excel or triggers Out of Stack Error.

Is there a way to write this more efficient?

Comment: `Out of Stack Error` hmmm... seems you came to the right place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off event handling or the Worksheet_Change will just try to run on top on itself when it writes values.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B8")) Is Nothing Then
        on error goto safe_exit
        application.enableevents = false
        Range("Input_Table").FormulaR1C1= Range("Input_Table").FormulaR1C1
    End If
safe_exit:
    application.enableevents = true
End Sub
```

You do not want to write formulas into values; it is possible that you might have a formula. Use .Value2 which is the raw underlying value devoid of date or regional currency 'markers'. The cell's original formatting will restore these to the .Value.

Comment: Hm so on the one hand the function runs smoothly now but for some reason it erases the formula in one of my columns. No idea why that is happening. But not the end of the world I could just keep those columns outside of the input table wanted to do that anyways.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay that makes sense is it possible to adapt the macro that those formulas do not get destroyed or am I better of being consistent and move those formulas outside of the input table?

Comment: My apologies; I misinterpreted your intentions. Corrected above.

Comment: Does exactly what I wanted now! You are an awesome Human keep it up. Hope you have a nice day !